# How to tar files with a sorted order?

Tags: linux, tar, sort

If you `tar` a directory recursively, it just uses the order from the os's `readdir`.

But in some cases it's nice to tar the files sorted.

What's a good way to tar a directory sorted alphabetically?

---

*Note, for the purpose of this question, gnu-tar on a typical Linux system is fine.*

Comment: possible duplicate of below,
Check below links

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120143/how-is-the-order-in-which-tar-works-on-files-determined

http://superuser.com/questions/172367/how-do-i-create-a-tar-file-in-alphabetical-order

Comment: I saw this, but Im not asking how the order is set, instead I want to sort them.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67018 for sorting a directory tree by name.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For a GNU `tar`:

```
--sort=ORDER
 Specify the directory sorting order when reading directories.
 ORDER may be one of the following:

`none'
      No directory sorting is performed. This is the default.

`name'
      Sort the directory entries on name. The operating system may
      deliver directory entries in a more or less random order, and
      sorting them makes archive creation reproducible.

`inode'
      Sort the directory entries on inode number. Sorting
      directories on inode number may reduce the amount of disk
      seek operations when creating an archive for some file
      systems.
```

You'll probably also want to look at `--preserve-order`.

Comment: `--sort` was introduced in tar version 1.28. `--preserve-order` is not relevant to this question.

Comment: I am keep having `tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors` error. @mhsmith

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`, instead of:

```
pax -w dir
```

Use:

```
pax -dw dir dir/**/*(D)
```

You can do the same with recent versions of `bash -O globstar -O dotglob` with:

```
pax -dw dir/**
```

Or recent versions of  `FIGNORE='@(.|..)' ksh93 -o globstar` with:

```
pax -dw dir dir/**
```

`pax` is the standard command to make `tar` files. The output goes to stdout. Shell globs are sorted by name.

If you run into an *Arg list too long* error, you can change to:

```
printf '%s\0' dir dir/**/*(D) | pax -0dw
```

(not all `pax` implementations support `-0` though).

Answer (score 2):

`tar` itself cannot do this, so you have to create it from a correctly ordered list. In principle you could then use `tar`'s  `-T` option, but there is no way to specify that the filenames in that list should be NUL terminated. So if you have any filenames with newlines in them (which is allowed) this will just break.

A better option is to use `cpio` to generate the files as that accepts a NUL terminated list of filenames and can generate tar files.

If your `tar` command would be:

```
tar cvf /somedir/all.tar .
```

Then for this to be sorted by name you would have to do (assuming GNU find and cpio):

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -z | \
  cpio --create --null --format=ustar -O /somedir/all.tar
```

This has the disadvantage though that subdirectories are placed in between filenames. You can do tricks with `find`s -printf0 specifying the directory and depth information and sorting with `sort -n` but that also influences how files with numbers are sorted within a directory.

If the above is not satisfactory you could probably use a small python program based on `os.walk()` to generate the ordering you want with full control (depth first, based on extenion etc), but if you go that route you might as well drop `cpio` and write out the `tar` file with python's `tarfile` module.

Comment: --null specifies that -T takes null terminated strings.

Comment: should set `LC_ALL=C` for sort, see https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/archives/ - `find build -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z | tar --no-recursion --null -T - -cf product.tar`